# JPEG-Compression, Time Complexity and Performance

Tags: compression, time-complexity, jpeg, cpu-usage

I have a few questions regarding JPEG-compression;

What is the typical time-complexity of a good implementation of a JPEG-compression algorithm? I've tried reading up on the process itself but as it turns out I find it quite hard to pinpoint exactly what processes that needs to be done - I'm still at a pretty basic level in my algorithm-knowledge.. :-)

And I also wonder (I guess this can be derived from the first question) how demanding JPEG-compression is for the CPU compared to different compression algorithms, e.g. .gif - say if I needed to compress 1000 photos for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean as a function of the size of the image, it's linear. The compression and decompression time are O(n), where n is the number of pixels.

JPEG and GIF are two different solutions to two different problems. JPEG is lossy generally for natural, photographic images, whereas GIF is lossless, generally for simple graphic images and icons. You would not use GIF for photographs.

Also GIF is obsolete, having been replaced with PNG, except for simple animated GIFs, of cats mostly. (There are better methods for lossless image compression than what PNG uses, but none seem to have caught on. The compression methods in PNG should be obsolete, but they aren't.)

Comment: O(n) is a reasonable estimate for a minimal JPEG encoder. The quality level affects the time as well. A compressed JPEG image that's twice as large (higher quality level) generally takes twice as long to create. There are other options that can make the process take longer (e.g. progressive mode, arithmetic encoding, custom Huffman tables).

Comment: Those are just constant factors in front of the _n_. It's O(n).

Comment: @MarkAdler So would you say the most commonly used lossless compression method for pictures is PNG, even though it's maybe not 'optimal'? What are the pros/cons of JPEG vs PNG? Is the PNG-compression algorithm more complex and therefore has a greater time complexity, or is it just as quick as JPEG-compression? Thank you so much for your great answer!

Comment: As I said, JPEG and PNG are for two different applications. The choice has nothing to do with speed.

Comment: In PNG the compression time is related to the "quality" selected. The more you search the dictionary window, the more time it takes. In JPEG the compression time is the same regardless of the "quality." It generally takes less time to compress JPEG than PNG and less time to expand PNG than JPEG. That said, the choice of which to use depends upon the type of image and the purpose of the storage.

Comment: @user3344003 Okay, that makes perfect sense - thanks for your answer!